# With Wake-on-lan enabled, computer will wake randomly with no WOL Signal sent

Tags: windows-8, sleep, wake-on-lan

I have enabled WOL on my custom PC in order to wake my PC for remote control. I have an Ethernet cable plugged directly into the Ethernet slot of my Realtek card.

When i put my PC to sleep, it will without fail wake itself up about 30mins-1hour later.

Looking in the event viewer, i have this wake event:

Kernel-Power - EventID 131

Details:

```
Firmware: 53 times. ResumeCount , FullResume 1006, AverageResume 1006
```

Is there anywhere i can find more details about this wake event? or has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Does this happen with the network cable unplugged?

Answer (score 2):

To change your system only to wake when it receives a 'magic packet' (google: wol or wakeonlan), go to Device Manager, locate your network card, right click for Properties and then 'Power Management' tab.

Leave checked 'allow this device to wake the computer', and check 'Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer'.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard might be configured to accept any direct network traffic, as opppsed to what is known as [the "Magic Packet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet).

In that state of configuration, your motherboard will accept any metwork traffic, instead of this particular packet used for waking your computer off.

The solution in this case would be to change what wakes it up, which on a Windows system would most likely be done from the settings for the network device.